# Errors when attempting to install CUDA through CMD

Tags: python, pip

When I've been attempting to install CUDA through Command Prompt, I get the following errors and have no idea how to fix them.

```
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\http\client.py", line 459, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\http\client.py", line 503, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 472, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 140, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 128, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 32, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 204, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 295, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 227, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 305, in _prepare_distribution
    return self._factory.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 508, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 550, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 239, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 102, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 145, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 144, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 541, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\silasm\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='download.pytorch.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I don't know how to fix this.

Also, everytime I try opening a Python file, it immediately shuts down after booting up. I assume this has something to do with conflicting versions of Python, but I have uninstalled all versions and reinstalled just 3.9. If there is something I can use to completely rid my computer of all things Python in order to start from the ground up, I would appreciate it very much as I've had more than just this problem when it comes to Python.

Comment: It says there in the stack trace (at the bottom): "The read operation timed out". Sounds like a network issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it looks like a temporary network issue. you can try to rerun the same command, and hopefully it is working. good luck out there.

Second, for different python versions, it is better to use conda to manage it. reference: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/index.html